# Constructing object twice

Tags: c++, class, constructor

```
class foo
{
  public:
    foo();
    foo(int param){foo::foo();}
};
```

Would `foo::foo(int)` call `foo::foo()` as method and initialize object's members or create nameless object? Can one constructor be called as a method from another constructor / member function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, your constructor will create a nameless object of the class `foo` and then it will be destroyed.

If you want to call a constructor from inside another constructor you can do it (only in C++11) with a **delegating constructor**

Example:

```
class foo
{
  public:
    foo();
    foo(int param) : foo() {}
};
```

Comment: is calling one constructor from another somehow possible in c++0x?

Comment: @user2543574 There's no such thing as c++0x. The answer of xorguy applies to C++11. Check the manual of your compiler to find out which C++11 features it supports. GCC supports delegating constructors since 4.7.